# Android App has unfortunately stopped Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse, runtime-error

I've just started to build my first android app and this 1st time errors are bugging me now since 2 days. Finding no solution I had to come here. I have been following Androids official tutorial for my first app and can't open my app.

Error: "Unfortunately "app name" has stopped"

Here is my manisfest file,

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="app2.android"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="17"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

  <activity android:name="MainActivity" >
     <intent-filter>  
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>

</application>
```

Error Logs : 
 Log Cat file screenshot
https://www.dropbox.com/s/05l0ytiqkl7eo8v/Capture2.JPG

Comment: Post your activity code

Comment: have you written **Petuuk** class..if then post it..

Comment: can you post the first line of your `Petuuk.java` file ? I mean the package line.

Comment: Are you sure that you have class `Petuuk` within `com.android.myapp` package

Comment: Does your class "Petuuk .java" is inside your com.android.myapp package??

Comment: Clean your project and run it again.

Comment: Try cleaning your project

Comment: check do you have at the top of your class this line : package com.android.myapp;

Comment: clean your project and build it again.

Comment: Replace your activity class with this code:``

Comment: No the "Petuuk.java" file is not present, since by default with the first android tutorial everything was generated automatically but not working for the Hello World program, I just googled and got some stuff and put it in. Its getting so irritating...3 days and counting. Can't even run the Hello World Program :(

Comment: I have provided new manisfest.xml file! Please check!

Answer (score 0):

Replace your class with this code:

```
package com.android.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class Petuuk extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // Replace it with your layout name
   }
}
```

Clean your project run again.

Comment: is it the R.java file? I couldn't find the class. Manisfest file is not the one thath exlipse generates automatically, since it was not working I was googling it and found some stuff and put on it to make it work.

Comment: create a new class name Petuuk.java in your src main package.